# application/vnd.android.package-archive not showing apk files in android 4.1

Tags: android

"application/vnd.android.package-archive" mime type not showing apk files in File manager.

In my chatting app , I want to show only apk files in File manager to select one of them to send it to another user. I used the mime type "application/vnd.android.package-archive" in the intent.
That worked fine in my device Galaxy j5 "android 6.0", but when i try in my another device Galaxy core one "android 4.1" , all folders in my File manager are empty and not showing any file with any type.

```
public void openFile(String mimeType) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType(mimeType);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // special intent for Samsung file manager
    Intent sIntent = newIntent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
    // if you want any file type, you can skip next line
    sIntent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", mimeType);
    sIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    Intent chooserIntent;
    if (getActivity().getPackageManager().resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null){
        // it is device with Samsung file manager
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sIntent, "Open file");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { intent});
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity() , "not samsung" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file");
    }

    try {
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_APK_FILE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No suitable File Manager was found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In android 6.0 all worked fine, but in android 4.1 File manager is empty of files.